# How to resolve a security risk warning regarding SHA1withRSA signature algorithm?

Tags: android, firebase, rsa, sha

Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA (weak)
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 1

Warning:
The certificate uses the SHA1withRSA signature algorithm which is considered a security risk. This algorithm will be disabled in a future update.

Comment: You resolve it by discontinuing its use. As the warning indicates, it is not secure. Specifically, the problem is with SHA1, not RSA. So for example SHA256 or SHA512withRSA would be ok.